# Why My dropdown menu has not gone after click my browser body?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i am click my 'services li' my dropdown menu show and hide but when i am click  My browser body my dropdown menu not hide. I am try to my best efforts but not solve this problem. Please solve this problem anyone expert person.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li  id="apple"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Services
         <i  class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>

         <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>

        </a>
        
                <ul id="valovasi" class="anas">
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="pinki"><a href="#">Portfolio  <i style="transform: rotate(-90deg)" class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                             <ul class="naznin">
                                    <li><a href="https://youtube.com" target="blank">Web Design</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>  
                                </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts Us</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script> 

document.querySelector("#apple").addEventListener("click",function(){

document.querySelector(".anas").classList.toggle("anika");

});

</script>

</body>
</html>


nav ul li{
    cursor: pointer;
    

}
nav{
    padding-bottom: 20000px;

}

nav ul li:selected{

    background: red
}

nav ul::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
nav ul  {  padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: green;
   
    
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;

}
nav ul lia {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul ul li{
    float: none
}
nav ul  ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left:0;
    background: #ff4d4d;
    width:240px ;
   display: none;
}

nav ul  ul ul{
    display: block
}
nav ul .anika{
    display: block;
}
nav ul li:hover{

    background: pink
}
nav ul li:hover > a{

    color: black;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(3):hover{

    background: red
}
nav ul li:nth-child(3):hover > a{

    color: yellow
}
nav ul ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100%;
    background: navy;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}
nav ul ul li:hover ul{
    opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: You need to add an `onclick` listener to your body that listens for clicks that happen anywhere except the `apple` element and potentially the dropdown itself. When that condition is met, hide the dropdown again, presumably by removing its `anika` class.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. I think this is the easiest way to use it.

```js
$('html,body').click(function() {
  $('#container').hide();
});

$('#menu').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#toggle').click(function(event) {
  $('#container').toggle();
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#" id="toggle">Toggle Menu First</a>
  <ul id="container">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=#>D</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=#>E</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```